# Wordpress Not appearing option to edit html files

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I wanted to do a bit of customization, which requires me to edit some html files regarding the header. But I can't seem to find the option to do that.

Do you know if I'm missing any kind of plugin or if I'm just searching wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses a template hierarchy to define which file should be called to display the HTML based on the post-type or taxonomy. You can have a detailed look into the file being called at the below url:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/